# Typescript: get last working day of last month in different browsers with different results

Tags: typescript, date, vuejs3, cross-browser

I have a simple Typescript Vue.js 3 component with an  (also tried with a datepicker with same results). It should render the last working day of last month as default value:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, computed } from "vue";

const lastWorkingDayOfLastMonth = computed(() => {
  const today = new Date();
  let lastDayOfMonth = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() - 1, 1);
  let lastWorkingDayOfMonth = new Date(lastDayOfMonth.getFullYear(), lastDayOfMonth.getMonth() + 1, 0);
  while (
    lastWorkingDayOfMonth.getDay() === 0 ||
    lastWorkingDayOfMonth.getDay() === 6
  ) {
    lastWorkingDayOfMonth.setDate(lastWorkingDayOfMonth.getDate() - 1);
  }
  return lastWorkingDayOfMonth.toISOString().substr(0, 10);
});
const selectedDate = ref(lastWorkingDayOfLastMonth.value);
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <input type="date" id="date" v-model="selectedDate" />
  </div>
</template>
```

For some reason, on the same machine, Firefox shows the correct date (currently 28 Feb 2023), but on Chrome/Edge it shows 27 Feb 2023.

It seems like some browsers may interpret the date input as local time, others may interpret it as UTC. I also tried adjust the date to the user's timezone by setting the timezone offset to zero, like this:

```js
const lastWorkingDayOfLastMonth = computed(() => {
  const today = new Date();
  let lastDayOfMonth = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() - 1, 1);
  let lastWorkingDayOfMonth = new Date(lastDayOfMonth.getFullYear(), lastDayOfMonth.getMonth() + 1, 0);
  while (lastWorkingDayOfMonth.getDay() === 0 || lastWorkingDayOfMonth.getDay() === 6) {
    lastWorkingDayOfMonth.setDate(lastWorkingDayOfMonth.getDate() - 1);
  }
  lastWorkingDayOfMonth.setMinutes(lastWorkingDayOfMonth.getMinutes() + lastWorkingDayOfMonth.getTimezoneOffset());
  return lastWorkingDayOfMonth.toISOString().substr(0, 10);
});
```

The results are the same. Does anyone know why Chrome/Edge show one day less than expected?

Comment: I tested your code on Chrome and Firefox and see the same result as expected. Seem like there are some extensions/settings that modified the time zone of one of your browsers. Important note, if you run `new Date(2023, 2, 0)` it will create a new Date object with the value `Feb 28, 2023 0:00:00` in `your time zone`. If you run `toISOString()` of that date object, it will show the date string in the UTC time zone. That means the result `might not` be `Feb 28` depending on your machine's timezone. If your time zone is UTC +x, it will be `Feb 27`. If your timezone is `UTC -x`, it will be `Feb 28`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in the right track but offsetting the hours wrongly. For the `toISOString()` show the time independently of time you must have hour 01:00:00 for GMT+0100, 02:00:00 for GMT+0200, and so on. Then you can offset it before printing like in the code:

```js
const lastWorkingDayOfLastMonth = computed(() => {
  const today = new Date();
  let lastDayOfMonth = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() - 1, 1);
  let lastWorkingDayOfMonth = new Date(lastDayOfMonth.getFullYear(), lastDayOfMonth.getMonth() + 1, 0);
  while (lastWorkingDayOfMonth.getDay() === 0 || lastWorkingDayOfMonth.getDay() === 6) {
    lastWorkingDayOfMonth.setDate(lastWorkingDayOfMonth.getDate() - 1);
  }
  lastWorkingDayOfMonth.setMinutes(lastWorkingDayOfMonth.getMinutes() - lastWorkingDayOfMonth.getTimezoneOffset());
  return lastWorkingDayOfMonth.toISOString().substr(0, 10);
});
```